# Alpha brush creates indent when applying over another alpha brush stroke

Tags: transparency, sculpting

i am trying to apply alpha brush to my sculpt and when i apply an alpha brush stroke over another it creates an indent around the previous stroke and warps the mesh. this is only a new problem as i have covered the rest of my model with the same alpha with no problems i am unsure as to what might be causing this. as you can see the part of the model on the right hand side is smooth and multiple alphas over the top of one and other.

any help would be much appreciated.

[image]